# Ace Editor highlight part of a line with marker

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am attempting to partially highlight a line / lines using a marker.

according to the [documentation on ranges](https://ace.c9.io/api/range.html) it it possible to create one with 4 inputs:  `startLine, startColumn, endLine, endColumn`

I fed such a range into an add marker method but it just highlights the entire lines

my code:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
var Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range;
editor.session.addMarker(
        new Range(startLine - 1, startPos, stopLine - 1, stopPos),
        "highlightError",
        "line",
        true
);
```

I think my problem may be to do with the 3rd argument of addMarker, the [documentation](https://ace.c9.io/api/edit_session.html#EditSession.addMarker) I managed to find only states that this should be the 'type of marker' but I cannot find what the available types of marker are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reaslised that the alternative option to 'line' was 'text' however setting this did not fix the issue for me. I ended up with hardly any highlighted area. Upon further research I realised that the markers created by `addMarker()` did not have their position set to absolute. I added `position: absolute;` to my highlightError class css and it fixed the issue and now highlights the correct text.

Answer (score 7):

Because selected answer was not clear enough, I add an example in this answer.

You need to add `position: absolute;` to the highlighting class.

For example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rezaamya/gvtxd3bf/8/) I am using `.blue` to make the selection to blue, then I should add `position: absolute;` to it.

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

var Range = ace.require("ace/range").Range;
editor.selection.setRange(new Range(4, 0, 6, 5));

editor.session.addMarker(new Range(0, 0, 1, 5), "blue", "text");
```

```css
#editor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.blue {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/ace/1.4.6/ace.js" integrity="sha256-CVkji/u32aj2TeC+D13f7scFSIfphw2pmu4LaKWMSY8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor">
function foo(items) {
    var x = items * items;
    return x;
}

var test = foo(2);

console.log(test); //should be 4

console.log(foo(1)); //should be 1

console.log(foo(3)); //should be 9
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "text" instead of "line" as a third argument.

Other supported types are "fullLine" and "screenLine" https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/layer/marker.js#L99

Answer (score 1):

For those who are searching for how to mark text by search, this is an example function to get the right marker position in text:

```
const getMarker = (regex): Marker => {
    const result = value?.match(`\\[${regex}]`);
    if (result?.index) {
         const start = editor.session.doc.indexToPosition(result.index + 1);
         const end = editor.session.doc.indexToPosition(result.index + text.length + 1);
         return {
              startRow: start.row,
              startCol: start.column,
              endRow: end.row,
              endCol: end.column,
              className: "custom-ace-marker",
              type: "text",
         };
    }
}
```

Notice you need to add the `custom-ace-marker` class with styles and `position: absolute` to get it working correctly:

```css
.custom-ace-marker {position: absolute; background: red}
```